# Shall I change order of integral and limit

Tags: integration, limits

I want to know whether I can change the order of integral and limit, as following
$$ \lim_\limits{\Delta x\rightarrow0}\frac{ \int_{a}^{b}y\left[ H(z+\frac{\Delta x}{y}) -H(z) \right]f(y)dy }{ \Delta x } 
=\int_a^b\left[ \lim_\limits{\Delta x\rightarrow0} \frac{ H(z+\frac{\Delta x}{y}) -H(z) }{ \frac{\Delta x}{y} } \right]f(y)dy \\
= \int_a^b H'(z) f(y)dy  $$

Or under which condition I can do this?

Comment: Look Up Dominated Convergence Theorem or Monotone Convergence Theorem

Comment: Is zero in the integration range?